# What is the closure of A when A is not connected?

Tags: general-topology

I have already what is a closure. I saw some examples of closure what A is something kind of this $(0,1)$. But when A is, for example, $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$, What is the closure of this? Is it $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$? So is this closure "closed"?

Comment: The closure of a set $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$. So it is always **closed**. If you want to find the closure of $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, it is exactly $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$.

Comment: These confusions with these kind of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the reason why this exercise of Rudin is so perfect: Find a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with exactly 3 limit points.

Comment: I understood now, I got confused between 2 terms "closed" and "disconnected". haha

Answer (score 1):

A set is (topologically) closed if it contains all of its limit point in its topological space.   The closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing the set.   Which entails that a closure for a set is the union of the set and its limit points.

The limit points for $(0;1)\cup(2;3)$ are $\{0,1,2,3\}$.   Thus $[0;1]\cup[2;3]$ is the closure, and of course it is closed.

The "hole" between the subintervals is no impediment to closure.   You do not need to fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

You can find closure with the help of Adherent points definition ,

$\bar{A}=A\cup D(A)$

where ,  $\bar{A}$ is closure of $A$ and $D(A)$ is the set of all limit points of $A$.